# How to save Random forest classifier within GEE that can be called later for classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, model

```js
var classifier_serialized = ee.Serializer.toJSON(classifier)
Export.table.toAsset(ee.FeatureCollection(empty_feature.set('classifier',json)),desc,AssetName)

// Load using this
var json = ee.String(ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(assetName).first()).get('classifier'))
var classifier = ee.Deserializer.fromJSON(json)
```

and

````js
var trees = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(classifier.explain()).get('trees'))
var dummy = ee.Feature()
var col = ee.FeatureCollection(trees.map(function(x){return dummy.set('tree',x)}))
Export.table.toAsset(col,'save_classifier',AssetName)

// Load classifier
var trees = ee.FeatureCollection(AssetName).aggregate_array('tree').aside(print)
var classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble(trees)
``

The above code answered earlier for similar question are not working or maybe I am doing it in wrong way.
Can you some ways? Below is my code:- 

```js
var final_image = img_final;

var bands = ['blue_band','green_band', 'red_band'];

var samples = TG_water_sample.merge(TG_Non_water_sample);

var data_fc = ee.FeatureCollection([]);

for ( var z = 0; z < new_col_size; z++ ){
  
  var rgb_image = ee.Image(new_col_list.get(z));
  
  var total_sample1 = rgb_image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection:samples,
  properties:['Property','LC'],
  scale: 20 });
  
  data_fc = data_fc.merge(total_sample1);
  
}

print('data_fc_size', data_fc.size() );

var total_sample = data_fc;
var final_image1 = rgb_coll.first();
print('final_image1', final_image1);

var sample_rc = total_sample.randomColumn('rand')

var training = sample_rc.filter(ee.Filter.lt('rand',0.80))
var validation = sample_rc.filter(ee.Filter.gte('rand', 0.80))

var RF_classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(50).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'LC',
  inputProperties: bands
}) 

var RF_classification = final_image1.classify(RF_classifier)

print('RF_classification', RF_classification );

Map.addLayer(RF_classification.clip(roi), {min: 0, max:1, palette: ['blue','green']}, 'RF classification by S1_rgb')
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to save my GEE random forest classifer as an Asset in Google earth engine, so later i can call the same classifier again to classify different image. It will avoid repeated training of model. Is this possible in Google earth engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to run your script, and you don't explain how it fails. I assume that your classification works, but you're have problems exporting the decision trees as an asset. You create a feature collection where each decision tree is a feature with a single `tree` property. Maybe you're running into the property length limitation? According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#to-asset_1):

> Maximum of 100,000 characters per string value

You could try to split your decision tree over multiple properties. Each feature can have up to 1,000 properties. I haven't run this for a larger decision tree, so maybe this still fail, but for other reasons.

```
var decisionTrees = ee.List(classifier.explain().get('trees'))

Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: encodeFeatureCollection(decisionTrees),
  description: 'decision-trees'
})

function encodeFeatureCollection(value) {
  var string = ee.String.encodeJSON(value)
  var stringLength = string.length()
  var maxLength = 100000
  var maxProperties = 1000
  var values = ee.List.sequence(0, stringLength, maxLength)
    .map(function (start) {
      start = ee.Number(start)
      var end = start.add(maxLength).min(stringLength)
      return string.slice(start, end)
    })
    .filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', ''))
  var numberOfProperties = values.size()
  return ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0, values.size(), maxProperties)
    .map(function (start) {
      start = ee.Number(start)
      var end = start.add(maxProperties).min(numberOfProperties)
      var propertyValues = values.slice(start, end)
      var propertyKeys = ee.List.sequence(1, propertyValues.size())
        .map(function (i) {
          return ee.Number(i).format('%d')
        })
      var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(propertyKeys, propertyValues)
      return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), properties)
    }).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['1']))
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1f0f994d1f2dab65ae9e8de2d82189d0

Here's how you can get the decision trees back from your asset:

```
// Note that I generated the asset with lower limits on property length and number of properties,
// to make sure the script works correctly
var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection('users/wiell/forum/decision-trees')
var decisionTrees = decodeFeatureCollection(featureCollection)
var classifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble(decisionTrees)
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20210729T100031_20210729T100410_T32TQM')
var classification = image.classify(classifier)

Map.centerObject(image)
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', max: 3000}, 'image')
Map.addLayer(classification, {min: 1, max: 3, palette: 'blue,green,red'}, 'classification')

function decodeFeatureCollection(featureCollection) {
  return featureCollection
    .map(function (feature) {
      var dict = feature.toDictionary()
      var keys = dict.keys()
        .map(function (key) {
          return ee.Number.parse(ee.String(key))
        })
      var value = dict.values().sort(keys).join()
      return ee.Feature(null, {value: value})
    })
    .aggregate_array('value')
    .join()
    .decodeJSON()
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/48a52a47279673d87dd00e103ff72f3e

Comment: It's really working now, you really solved my issue. now its easily gets saved in assests and i can also call it back to classify any other test roi. Thanks alot. Want to learn more from you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I couldn't get this to work for a larger forest, any suggestions? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443481/save-large-random-forest-trees-for-repeated-use-in-google-earth-engine