# Export large Random Forest decision trees to Asset for repeated use in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to store a random forest classifier as an asset for repeated use. I followed this thread: [How to save Random forest classifier within GEE that can be called later for classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432355/how-to-save-random-forest-classifier-within-gee-that-can-be-called-later-for-cla) and found that it works for a small random forest (50 trees) but not a larger forest (500 trees). I am able to print the large forest, and print an classified image trained by the large forest, but when I `Map.addLayer(classifiedImage)` I get "Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum".

Because it works for the small forest not the large, I suspect I am running into some limitations when encoding the FeatureCollection. **How can I save and retrieve a large forest from Assets to use for classification?**

Script to encode the trees: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fddeb4fbc9cdeaba992525d2ed49108b

```
var trainingData = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-caseyengstrom/assets/globalSnowAlgae/2_trainDat/clean_train_3");

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
    numberOfTrees: 500, 
    variablesPerSplit: 1,
    minLeafPopulation: 2, 
    seed: 0
})
var bands = ["ND2_1","ND2_11","ND2_12","ND5_2","ND6_2",
                    "ND5_3","ND4_2","ND2_8A","ND2_9","ND5_6",
                    "ND4_8","ND2_7","ND5_4","ND6_3","ND2_8",
                    "ND4_6", "RGND", "GBND", "NDSI"]
                    
var trainedClassifier = classifier.train(trainingData, 'CLASS', bands)

var decisionTrees = ee.List(trainedClassifier.explain().get('trees'))
// print(decisionTrees)
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: encodeFeatureCollection(decisionTrees),
  description: 'decision-trees'
})

// from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432355/how-to-save-random-forest-classifier-within-gee-that-can-be-called-later-for-cla
function encodeFeatureCollection(value) {
  var string = ee.String.encodeJSON(value)
  var stringLength = string.length()
  var maxLength = 1000000// added a zero here
  var maxProperties = 1000
  var values = ee.List.sequence(0, stringLength, maxLength)
    .map(function (start) {
      start = ee.Number(start)
      var end = start.add(maxLength).min(stringLength)
      return string.slice(start, end)
    })
    .filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', ''))
  var numberOfProperties = values.size()
  return ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0, values.size(), maxProperties)
    .map(function (start) {
      start = ee.Number(start)
      var end = start.add(maxProperties).min(numberOfProperties)
      var propertyValues = values.slice(start, end)
      var propertyKeys = ee.List.sequence(1, propertyValues.size())
        .map(function (i) {
          return ee.Number(i).format('%d')
        })
      var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(propertyKeys, propertyValues)
      return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]), properties)
    }).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['1']))
  )
}
```

Script to decode the trees: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2aadd95ce7b0ab32df5b4d379018a2db

```
var jsonDecisionTrees = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-caseyengstrom/assets/globalSnowAlgae/2_trainDat/decision_trees"),
    jsonDecisionTreesSmall = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-caseyengstrom/assets/globalSnowAlgae/2_trainDat/decision_trees-small");

var image = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200718T184919_20200718T185613_T11UMS")
Map.centerObject(image, 8)

// load 500 precomputed decision trees
var decisionTrees = decodeFeatureCollection(jsonDecisionTrees)
print(decisionTrees) // works
var trainedClassifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble(decisionTrees)

// classify the image
var normalized = normalizeBands(image) // pre-processing
var classified = normalized.classify(trainedClassifier, 'CLASSIFICATION').rename('CLASSIFICATION')

print(classified) // works
Map.addLayer(classified, {}, "class") // ERROR! Description length exceeds maximum.



// no problem using a smaller classifier (only 50 trees)
var decisionTreesSmall = decodeFeatureCollection(jsonDecisionTreesSmall)
var smallTrainedClassifier = ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble(decisionTreesSmall)
var classifiedSmall = normalized.classify(smallTrainedClassifier, 'CLASSIFICATION').rename('CLASSIFICATION')
Map.addLayer(classifiedSmall, {}, "class, smaller asset") 


// from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432355/how-to-save-random-forest-classifier-within-gee-that-can-be-called-later-for-cla
function decodeFeatureCollection(featureCollection) {
  return featureCollection
    .map(function (feature) {
      var dict = feature.toDictionary()
      var keys = dict.keys()
        .map(function (key) {
          return ee.Number.parse(ee.String(key))
        })
      var value = dict.values().sort(keys).join()
      return ee.Feature(null, {value: value})
    })
    .aggregate_array('value')
    .join()
    .decodeJSON()
}

// a pre-processing step for the classifier
function normalizeBands(image){
  image = ee.Image(image)
  
  var NDSI = image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B11']).rename('NDSI')
  var RGND = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']).rename('RGND')
  var GBND = image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B2']).rename('GBND')
  
  var imagePlus = image
    .addBands(RGND)
    .addBands(NDSI)
    .addBands(GBND)
  
  var ND2_1 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B1']).rename('ND2_1')
  var ND2_11 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B11']).rename('ND2_11')
  var ND2_12 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B12']).rename('ND2_12')
  var ND5_2 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B2']).rename('ND5_2')
  var ND6_2 = image.normalizedDifference(['B6','B2']).rename('ND6_2')
  var ND5_3 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B3']).rename('ND5_3')
  var ND4_2 = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B2']).rename('ND4_2')
  var ND2_8A = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B8A']).rename('ND2_8A')
  var ND2_9 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B9']).rename('ND2_9')
  var ND5_6 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B6']).rename('ND5_6')
  var ND4_8 = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B8']).rename('ND4_8')
  var ND2_7 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B7']).rename('ND2_7')
  var ND5_4 = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('ND5_4')
  var ND6_3 = image.normalizedDifference(['B6','B3']).rename('ND6_3')
  var ND2_8 = image.normalizedDifference(['B2','B8']).rename('ND2_8')
  var ND4_6 = image.normalizedDifference(['B4','B6']).rename('ND4_6')
  
  
  return imagePlus
      .addBands(ND2_1)
      .addBands(ND2_11)
      .addBands(ND2_12)
      .addBands(ND5_2)
      .addBands(ND6_2)
      .addBands(ND5_3)
      .addBands(ND4_2)
      .addBands(ND2_8A)
      .addBands(ND2_9)
      .addBands(ND5_6)
      .addBands(ND4_8)
      .addBands(ND2_7)
      .addBands(ND5_4)
      .addBands(ND6_3)
      .addBands(ND2_8)
      .addBands(ND4_6)
}
```

**UPDATE** 2023-02-12
Exporting the classified image works fine. The issue seems to be specific to Map.addLayer.